# Case Settings Deployment Issue

Tags: deployment, case

I am trying to deploy Case Settings to Sandbox via Metadata API and I am getting the following error:

> The Email Address Name is not valid

I verified that the email and the user associated with the email specified in the Case.Settings XML file actually exists in the system

```
<defaultCaseOwner>xyz@abc.com</defaultCaseOwner>
<defaultCaseOwnerType>User</defaultCaseOwnerType>
<defaultCaseUser>xyz@abc.com</defaultCaseUser>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not an email address (because email addresses are not unique). Instead, it is the user's *user name*, which will be different from production, usually in the form of `username@domain.org.sandboxname`. Make sure that the username matches the value for `defaultCaseOwner` and `defaultCaseUser`.

Comment: xyz@abc.com is username in Production, the same user exists in the Sandbox with username xyz@abc.com.qa. I tried all combinations while deployment. Nothing working out.

Comment: @smhvrtyj That's odd. It works well in my developer org. The documentation doesn't go into further detail about this, though.